# Selecting HttpHandler from custom HttpModule

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an HttpModule and I'd like to choose the HttpHandler for the current request, is that possible? Also `web.config` is not an option because the condition is not based on path or extension. My googling skills have failed me, no matter what keywords I use all the results are "IHttpHandler vs IHttpModule".

Comment: After spending a couple more hours I finally managed to find a solution : [HttpContext.RemapHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.remaphandler.aspx) This allows me to conditionally remap a request to a different handler at my Url rewriting module.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an HttpModule that will run on every request from the Client(Browser).

See here how he has used cookies to send timezoneOFfset by using HttpModule.

http://weblogs.asp.net/cprieto/archive/2010/01/03/handling-timezone-information-in-asp-net.aspx

Download the code and see how the things are working.

Definately you need some config changes.

Comment: I already have an HttpModule running, what I need is to choose which handler will be executed by checking some conditions in this HttpModule, thanks